# Follow HTTP redirect

Tags: c#

I want to use Dropbox to hold all of my data and then have my application download it. To make the download link a direct download is pretty simple, you just add "?raw=1" at the end.

However it will cause an HTTP redirect. How can I make the WebClient follow it?

```
string MySQLData = "http://downloadfile.com";

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(MySQL_Check);
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompleted_MySQL;
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(MySQLData.Trim()), RootWindow_TextBox_SaveToDir.Text + "/" + "MySQL Data" + Path.GetExtension(MySQLData));
```

Comment: Does it not follow it by default? I'm not familiar with the behavior of `WebClient`, but a quick search sure makes it seem like it should. Or do you need to know the value of the Location header from the 302?

Comment: I'm almost positive WebClient follows 302s without problems.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Yes, I forgot that WebClient will automatically follow HTTP redirects. So I believe I do need the location header.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and answer this question. This is how to get the URI redirect.

```
            var request = WebRequest.Create(MyDownloadLink);
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Then you can just call.

```
 response.ResponseUri.ToString()
```